# file from the docker container is read-only

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, docker-compose, pycharm, dockerfile

When I switched my IDE from VSCode to PyCharm, I encountered an issue where I couldn't write to files inside the container. I received a message stating "file from the docker container is read-only." Strangely, when using VSCode, I was able to make changes to files within the container. Has anyone else experienced this problem(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Abm6V.png)

Even after trying to grant all permissions using the command "chmod -R 777 .", the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue, please vote for below YouTrack ticket for the update.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-330529